# How to prevent paypal auto changing order status from processing to complete magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal, order-status, paypal-standard

noticed that the paypal standard module automatically transfers orders to the status of complete. How to prevent him from doing this? it does not work correctly, since the status complete means that the products were sent.

[image]